# Add contact list on windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I want to add a contact list in my windows phone 8 project.I already did that using long list selector but it not worked on phone Panorama.I want contact list on phone Panorama.

Comment: what was the problem with longlist on panorama ??

Answer (score 0):

try this code ...
longlist selector works fine on panaroma ...

just change the list binded with your own list and make the datatemplate according to ypour wish it will work fine ...

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="first item">
                <!--Single line list with text wrapping-->
                <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-22,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,-6,0,12">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>
```